# Allophones of /ə/

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

In (non-rhotic) British English there seem to be two major allophones of the phoneme /ə/. The first which can be heard in *p**o**tato, c**a**reer* or the weak form of *fr**o**m* as an [ə].

However, there's also a second allophone which it appears doesn't get much attention throughout the scientific literature. In fact, I have only found information about it in *Gimson's Pronunciation of English (7th edition):*

> In final positions, e.g. in 'moth*er*, doct*or*, ov*er*, pict*ure*, Chin*a*', the vowel may be articulated in the open-mid central position (= [ə̞]). The acoustic formants of /ə/ are, therefore, likely to be similar to those for /ɜː/ or /ʌ/ according to the situation.

*Note:* [ə̞] (= lowered [ə]) is meant to be [ɜ] on the IPA vowel chart.

But what about compound words like *moth**er**hood, int**er**net, int**er**stellar* and so on? Do these also take the somewhat lowered schwa as if they were single words?

Comment: Are you sure that "lowered [ə]" isn't meant to be [ʌ] rather than [ɜ]? Take a look at the [actual British vowel positions](https://www.llas.ac.uk/materialsbank/mb081/page_10.htm). That's not the right position for the strict IPA vowel [ʌ], but over the last century, in RP, /ʌ/ has moved from being back of /ɜː/ to below it, and nobody has changed the phoneme's symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right about the distinction, whichever IPA symbols are appropriate.  In younger London speech, final schwa may be closer to /ɑ/, so 'mother' may be pronounced /ˈmʌðɑ/.  But the same speaker would probably say 'potato' as /pəˈtɑɪtɑʊ/ with the traditional schwa in the first syllable.